# Set index.php file to only show posts from one category

Tags: php, wordpress

Here is a copy of my index.php file, which i gather governs what is shown on the posts page. Im wanting the posts page to only show the posts from my "blog" category. Can someone help with the code changes that i need to make, to implement this?

Thanks heaps guys
Erin

```
<?php 
$archive_page_layout = esc_attr(of_get_option('archive_page_layout'));
?>
    <main id="main" class="site-main clearfix <?php echo esc_attr($archive_page_layout); ?>">
        <?php if($archive_page_layout == 'both-sidebar'): ?>
            <div id="primary-wrap" class="clearfix">
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div id="primary" class="content-area">

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php
                        /* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                         * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                         * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                         */
                        get_template_part( 'content' , 'blog' );
                    ?>

                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php the_posts_navigation(); ?>

            <?php else : ?>

                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>

            <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #primary -->

        <?php 
        if($archive_page_layout == 'both-sidebar' || $archive_page_layout == 'left-sidebar'): 
            get_sidebar('left');
        endif; 
        ?>

        <?php if($archive_page_layout == 'both-sidebar'): ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
        if($archive_page_layout == 'both-sidebar' || $archive_page_layout == 'right-sidebar'): 
            get_sidebar('right');
        endif; 
        ?>
    </main><!-- #main -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use **argument parameters** to specify a posts categorie/s please refer to 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/145125/display-content-from-a-specific-category for the code you will need.

:)